# Basis of $H^1(\Omega)$ which is orthonormal wrt. $L^2(\partial\Omega)$ inner product?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, orthonormal

Let $\Omega$ be a domain with $\partial\Omega$ bounded.

Is it possible to find a smooth basis of $H^1(\Omega)$ and $L^2(\Omega)$ which is orthonormal wrt. the $L^2(\partial\Omega)$ inner product?

Often one would take the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on $\Omega$ but this doesn't give us any information about the boundary requirement.. is there another way?

Comment: I think the eigenfunctions you find from Laplacian is $C^\infty$ functions, is this not enough?

Comment: @wisher But those would not be orthogonal in $L^2$ on the boundary.

Comment: But those functions has $0$ boundary conditions right?

Comment: Have you studied the Spherical Harmonics?

Comment: @T.A.E. Hi I have not studied that. I will look it up.

Comment: @wisher Maybe we need to think what Laplacian? Probably it cannot be the zero Dirichlet-Laplacian which you are thinking of??

Comment: Why not? I think you get eigenvalue from the Dirichlet problem